# Calculating the limit of the following:

Tags: calculus, limits

This must be very simple and straightforward for many of you, yet I do not see the solution. Could you show me a solution to this? With/without L'Hospital rule, preferably both ways?

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\frac1{1+x^2}}{1-\cos(x)+3\sin^2(x)\cos(x)}$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You may not be aware of this, but please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22), which includes adding context, showing your work, and paying the thanks forwards (saying "Thanks" is unnecessary, rather, you should vote and accept). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, now I am aware of this. Just to see this clear, attaching an image of the original problem (and not writing it in Latex) is then forbidden?

Thank you for the guides, I will take a close look!

Comment: It's certainly not forbidden, but you should use LaTeX when possible. Images cannot be searched for, and they may not be view-able to some users e.g. restricted wifi censoring images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The reciprocal is easier, because it is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x+3\sin^2x\cos x}{x^2}\,(1+x^2)=
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}+3\cos x\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\right)(1+x^2)
$$

Comment: Solved practically by your hint, thank you!